# Any way to achieve google appengine multi-region serving?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm using App Engine Standard Environment.

I'm allowed to choose one region to serve on project creation.

[image]

Lets assume clients of my app are world-spread (America, Europe, Asia), and all of them are equally-important.

Latency difference is significant (I'm in Europe now, simple Hello world page sample is ~200ms if I choose us-central region, and ~080ms if I choose Europe region).

Any way to achieve multi-region serving on appengine? Can I easy move to GKE or smth to archive this?

Glad to hear any theoretical explanations-comments on multi-region serving.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know enough about App Engine or the [App Engine Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/) to know if you can run the same app in multiple regions and load balance between them, but I do know that you can do multi-region serving from GKE or GCE using [HTTP(S) Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/).

You can easily move from the App Engine Flexible Environment to GKE as they both use Docker containers for deploying your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an HTTPS Load balancer with [Serverless NEG](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/setting-up-serverless-negs) backend for GAE multi-region serving. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62660953/4185100